# The method onItemRightClick(ItemStack, World, EntityPlayer, EnumHand) of type ItemVoidPickaxe must override or implement a supertype method

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am trying to make an item that gets damaged on right click. The only issue is... Well, the error is the title of this question... And the quick fix is to remove the @Override annotation but then it won't actually do anything... Here is my code:

```
package com.AFranklin78000.VoidMod.items;

import javax.xml.ws.Action;

import com.AFranklin78000.VoidMod.Refrence;
import com.AFranklin78000.VoidMod.VoidMod;

import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayerMP;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemPickaxe;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer;
import net.minecraft.util.ActionResult;
import net.minecraft.util.EnumHand;
import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation;
import net.minecraft.world.World;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLCommonHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;

public class ItemVoidPickaxe extends ItemPickaxe {

public ItemVoidPickaxe(ToolMaterial material, String unlocalizedName) {
    super(material);
    this.setUnlocalizedName(unlocalizedName);
    this.setRegistryName(new ResourceLocation(Refrence.MODID, unlocalizedName));
    this.setCreativeTab(VoidMod.tabVoidMod);
}


@Override
public public ItemStack onItemRightClick(ItemStack itemstack, World worldIn, EntityPlayer playerIn, EnumHand handIn) {

    if (true) {
        if (playerIn instanceof EntityPlayerMP) {
            MinecraftServer minecraftserver = FMLCommonHandler.instance().getMinecraftServerInstance();
            if (minecraftserver != null)
                minecraftserver.getCommandManager().executeCommand((EntityPlayerMP) playerIn, "gamerule sendCommandFeedback false");
                minecraftserver.getCommandManager().executeCommand((EntityPlayerMP) playerIn, "particle portal ~ ~1 ~ 0 0 0 2.5 5000");
                minecraftserver.getCommandManager().executeCommand((EntityPlayerMP) playerIn, "fill ~5 ~5 ~5 ~-5 ~ ~-5 air 0 destroy");
        }
    }
    return onItemRightClick(itemstack, worldIn, playerIn, handIn);
}


}
```

This is Java code. And this is a Gradle... Thing...

So if you can help, that would be amazing!

Remember, I am not THAT great at coding yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, turns out that I needed to use: `playerIn.getHeldItemMainhand().damageItem(1, playerIn);`

Instead of: `itemstack.damageItem(1, playerIn);`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've nothing to do with Gradle, but reading your error message, shouldn't your method look like this?

```
@Override 
public ItemVoidPickaxe onItemRightClick(ItemStack itemstack, World worldIn, EntityPlayer playerIn, EnumHand handIn) {
    super(...);
    // the rest of the code
}
```

It seems somehow that you are mixing up methods...

Comment: I didn't know that! Thanks!

Comment: Wait... What do you put inside the `super("Here");`

Comment: As I told you, I have zero experience with Gradle. I only know how to code in Java and to interpret error messages. I'd suggest that you'll have a look at the ItemVoidPickaxe and ItemPickaxe classes. Somewhere you'll find the constructor. It should then be clear what you can put in. Maybe it's already sufficient to just call "super();". Just give it a try.

Comment: Ok. I'll do that